# Change in source value in calling method

Tags: c#, list, variables, scope

I have been trying to change source list but got confused with the way.

**Method 1 :**

```
        static void ChangeListWithoutAddRange(List<string> list) // 
        {
            var tempList = new List<string>() {"Three", "Four"};
            list = tempList;
        }
```

**Method 2:**

```
    static void ChangeListWithAddRange(List<string> list)
    {
        var tempList = new List<string>() { "Three", "Four" };
        list.Clear();
        list.AddRange(tempList);
    }
```

Testing above methods :

```
        var list = new List<string>() {"One", "Two"};
        ChangeListWithoutAddRange(list); //count is 0, 
        ChangeListWithAddRange(list); // change in list value , "Three" and "Four"
```

I am expecting both methods to change source list but Method 2 only changing source list as both method assigning value to list. Is there any specific reason about it?

Comment: Your really expect the first method to change the passed list? Come on, this is pretty basic. `ref` arguments etc.

Comment: Yes, I know about ref. But only most confusing part I am getting is second method where it changes method parameter value. What impression I've got is that method parameter only scoped to its method body untill and unless parameter is passed by ref/out.

Comment: You are mixing the object **content** with object **reference**. Every method can change the passed object content (assuming there are mutation methods), but only methods with `ref/out` can change the variable holding the object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

templist is a local variable in the scope of each method.

In the first method you copy the refernce of templist to the original list and once the method is over templist (and original list) get released by the garbage collector.

In method 2 addRange is copying the values to the list and at the end of the method templist is released.

Comment: Method parameter only scoped to its method body untill and unless parameter is passed by ref/out, Am I wrong?

Comment: The parameter is always scoped inside the function. When you pass something as a parameter, the parameter is a copy of what's being passed.
Now when we're talking about value types as aparameters, in order to change them, you need ref or out. but when passing a reference type. it makes a copies the reference and makes changes to the actual value that's stored in that ref. at the end of the function, the copy of the ref is deleted(not the content to which it references).

Comment: P.S if you want a ref type passed as a parameter not to be changed, you add "readonly" before the parameter.
Just to be clear, List is a ref type and in the real world to protect your data, lists are always passed as readonly to avoid losing your data like in Method 1

Comment: more about value and reference types here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx